# Why does irb insert control characters into my reverse-interactive-search buffer?

Tags: ruby, readline, irb, control-characters, ledit

If I do a reverse interactive search in irb and then enter a control character (arrow keys are the only ones I've seen this with actually). So I start with this session:

```
$ irb
>> print "hello"
hello
```

then enter `^r`, `h`

```
$ irb
>> print "hello"
hello
(reverse-i-search)`he': print "hello"
```

So far so good. Then I hit the left arrow, and I end up with this:

```
$ irb
>> print "hello"
hello
>> print "[Dhello"
```

Subsequent use of the arrows moves the cursor around normally.

Comment: I suggest you add tag `readline`.

Answer (score 3):

This won't solve your problem, but at least I can answer the question you asked (the Why):

The left arrow gets entered into the terminal as three characters, ESC, [, and D.  (You can test this by typing `read` and pressing the left arrow, which displays `^[[D`, where `^[` is how the escape character gets rendered.)

Somehow `irb` picks up the ESC character when it shouldn't; so ESC ends the history search, and `[D` gets entered literally.  Looking at other programs using readline, Bash and Python behave correctly, but `ledit` (yeah, obscure -- sorry ^^) is having this problem as well.

Unless someone knows a solution for this, the only workaround I can think of is pressing ESC instead of an arrow key to exit history search.  Or hitting enter if you don't need to edit further, of course.

Comment: I didn't know/realize that hitting ESC would select the history item and also leave my cursor in place, so that by itself is very useful. (I had been doing control-a or control-e)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have vi editing mode enabled?

```
~  $ irb
1.9.3p392 :001 > Readline.vi_editing_mode?
  => true
```

I had it turned on in my `$HOME/.inputrc` file via `set editing-mode vi`.  Disabling it "fixed" my arrow-keys.

As mentioned by @JoLiss, other readline programs (bash, etc.) were also working correctly; so AFAICT, it's a Ruby problem.  See: http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7859#change-36333